# How can I have one Docker container link to a postgres db in another Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.4"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

I use it to bring up the postgres db like this:

```
docker-compose up
```

Now I can connect to the db locally:

```
> psql postgres://postgres:postgres@docker-machine:5432
psql (9.6.4, server 9.4.13)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

My app is a Ruby/Sinatra app which connects to the postgres db.

When I start the app directly, using a `bin/server` script, the app boots up and connects to the db just fine.

This is how I build and run the dockerized app:

```
docker build -t my_app .

docker run \
  -p 3001:3001 \
  -e DATABASE_URI="postgres://postgres:postgres@docker-machine:5432" \
  my_app bin/server
```

When I run the app via Docker like this, it fails to connect to the db, and prints this error:

```
Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "docker-machine" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

How can I get my dockerized app to connect to the postgres db at the provided URI?

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of the followings:

1. Bring up both containers at the same time using the same docker-compose fil
2. You could use a name server which will allow you to use a name for your DB container so that would be visible from inside your App container
3. You could just use the DB container IP address, however, in case the DB container crashes and restarts it would have a different IP address which will make your App container brake.

Your App container tries to connect to localhost (inside the container itself) of course it cant because there's no Postgres running.

Comment: I've tried bringing it up as a service in the same `docker-compose` file, but get the same error. I have tried with the urls `"postgres://postgres:postgres@docker-machine:5432"` and `"postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432"`

Answer (score 0):

As the error states docker-machine isn't found. While this will work on the host as it wouldn't in the container. You could pass in the hostname as an environment variable like

`docker run .. -e HOST_HOSTNAME=hostname ..`

Then use that variable in your connection string

Comment: But what would I set that hostname value to?

Answer (score 0):

Docker Compose creates a [user defined network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks) by default for version 2+ compose files.

User defined networks come with an [embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) that can respond for the local container names. In this case, the service name `postgres` will resolve to the IP of your database on the user defined network compose creates.

To connect your app to the same network, modify your existing compose file, or create a new compose file in the same directory with your apps details.

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.4"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  my_app:
    build: .
    image: my/app
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    environment:
      DATABASE_URI: 'postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432'
    command: 'bin/server'
```

Then each containers IP will be available by its `service` name.